# P/Invoke: Fatal error. Invalid Program: attempted to call a NativeCallable method from runtime-typesafe code

Tags: c#, linux, signals, pinvoke

I am trying to catch kill signal in background task on Linux system (Ubuntu) using sigaction from libstd. Here is my Program class and DllImport declarations:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Signal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var pid = LibStd.GetPid();
            Console.WriteLine($"PID: {pid}");

            var sa = new Sigaction()
            {
                Handler = SignalHandler
            };

            LibStd.SigEmptySet(sa.Mask);
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(sa));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sa, ptr, true);

            _ = Task.Run(async() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Check SIGUSR1
                    if (LibStd.Sigaction(10, ptr, IntPtr.Zero) == -1)
                    {
                        // error
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(1);
                }
            });

            while (true)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }

        static LibStd.SignalHandler SignalHandler = new LibStd.SignalHandler(Handler);

        static void Handler(int sig)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"RECEIVED SIGNAL {sig}");
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Sigaction
    {
        public LibStd.SignalHandler Handler;
        public IntPtr Mask;
        public int Flags;
    }

    internal static class LibStd
    {
        private const string LibName = "c";

        [DllImport(LibName, EntryPoint = "getpid")]
        internal static extern int GetPid();

        [DllImport(LibName, EntryPoint = "sigaction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern int Sigaction(int sig, IntPtr act, IntPtr oldact);

        [DllImport(LibName, EntryPoint = "sigemptyset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern int SigEmptySet(IntPtr mask);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal delegate void SignalHandler(int t);
    }
}
```

I need to check for signals in background because I want to put this code in desktop GUI app in future so signal handling shouldn't block UI thread. 
However, when I run this program, then call `kill -SIGUSR1 <pid>` it outputs to the console following error:
**Fatal error. Invalid Program: attempted to call a NativeCallable method from runtime-typesafe code.**
If I put signal handling into main `while (true) { }` loop it works as expected.

It could be great if someone could help me to fix it. Thank you

Comment: you should probably either use async main and await the task, or use .Wait(). Without this your main method may end before your task has completed. Not sure if this is related to your problems, but it might be.

Comment: @JonasH, nope, sorry. main method is in infinite loop so it wont finish before task execution. The problem is related to P/Invoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18 I found that the structure needed was

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Sigaction
{
    public LibStd.SignalHandler Handler;
    public IntPtr Mask;
    public int Flags;
    public LibStd.SignalHandler sa_restorer;
}
```

consider not starting a thread for the signal processing

```
static private void ListenToSignal()
{
    var sa = new Sigaction()
    {
        Handler = SignalHandler
    };

    LibStd.SigEmptySet(sa.Mask);
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(sa));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(sa, ptr, true);

    if (LibStd.Sigaction(10, ptr, IntPtr.Zero) == -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sigaction -1");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Sigaction done");        
}
```

This sets up the processing on the main thread. When a signal arrives it get processed on it too. There is no need to keep polling the Sigaction

Comment: yeah, I've made it in the same way. Thank you for help